# “sed” error when using characters »<« and »>« in script

Tags: regex, sed, cygwin

I am trying to remove some cpp #include statement from some source code. I decided to do this with very great utility called "sed". When I try to execute "sed.exe" in the following ways:

```
sed -re '/#include \<syslog\.h\>/ d' < syslog.h > changed_syslog.h
sed -re '/#include <syslog\.h>/ d' < syslog.h > changed_syslog.h
```

I get error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unterminated address rege
```

If I try the following line:

```
sed -re '/#include .syslog\.h./ d' < syslog.h > changed_syslog.h
```

then everything works as expected.

Now what I want to know is what am I doing wrong in the first two commands?

I am using sed.exe from Cygwin 1.7.17.

syslog.h file looks in the following way (only one line):

```
#include <syslog.h>
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `sed -r '/#include \<syslog\.h\>/d' syslog.h > changed_syslog.h`?

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew -r stands for use extended regular expressions in the script and -e stands for add the script to the commands to be executed. I have also tried your command line but I get the same error.

Comment: I know what `re` does. The `file` argument needs no `<` before it for sure. `e` is just redundant here

Comment: Note that `\<` and `\>` mean start/end of word in sed, there is no need to quote `<` or `>` in a regexp or the RHS of a subsitution command if you surround the sed command by single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` is complaining that the 'address regular expression' is unterminated. The address regular expression is `/#include \<syslog\.h\>/`, so this implies that `sed` isn't seeing the final `/`.

In this case, the problem is that the the Windows shell is treating the `<` and `>` characters in `<syslog\.h>` as redirects. The solution is to quote them using `^`:

```
sed -re '/#include ^<syslog\.h^>/ d'
```

Comment: Yes you are right when I run the sed command with the script from file then it works.So, my solution is to put the script '/#include <syslog\.h>/ d' into the file script.sed and then run the sed in the following way: sed -r -f script.sed. And I forgot to mention that I run this command from batch file. You are also right about the characters "<" and ">" which are obvious special characters in the windows command line. Another better solution is to escape this characters "<" and ">" in the following way: sed -r '/#include ^<syslog\.h^>/ d' then it works also.

Comment: No problems, Joe. Thanks for the suggested edit - I've incorporated it and cut out a load of fluff